# Error with dcases*

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases

I'm using LaTeX to write up my math notes and have been fairly successful implementing most of the styles I'm trying to figure out.  I seem to be having trouble with the environment `dcases*` though.

Using the code

```
\item Let $g: \N \rightarrow \N$ be given by $n=$ 
\begin{dcases*} 
$1$ & if $n=1$ \\ 
$n-1$ & if $n \not = 1$ 
\end{dcases*}
```

gives me an error saying that it can only be used in math mode. Then it gives me a bunch of errors surrounding missing deliminators, but there aren't any missing.  The other weird thing is that it does display properly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you meant something like the following, note that `dcases` *must* be in `mathmode`, and ideally in `displayed mathmode` such as

- `\[...\]`
- `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`
- `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Let $g: N \rightarrow N$ be given by 
\[
    n=
    \begin{dcases*} 
        1 & if $n=1$ \\ 
        n-1 & if $n \ne 1$
    \end{dcases*}
\]

\end{document}
```

For future reference, you can view pages 17 and 18 of [`the documentation`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mh/mathtools.pdf) which describe that

- `dcases` puts every column in `mathmode`
- `dcases*` puts only the *first* column in `mathmode`, and the second column in the normal roman font of the document (hence the need to step back into `mathmode` in the second column)